MongoDB ECCONREFUSED when connecting to MongoDB Compass
I am trying to learn Node.JS from scratch. I am trying to connect index.js to MongoDB compass when I get the error:
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/Programming/website/learningNode/mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:897:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/Programming/website/learningNode/mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:848:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        minRoundTripTime: 0,
        lastUpdateTime: 31356356,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/Programming/website/learningNode/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:353:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/Programming/website/learningNode/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:268:44)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:635:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:170:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1607:16) {
            errno: -111,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 27017
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

I have used mongosh to make sure that the connection string is correct and working fine. MongoDB service is up and running.
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

// Create an Express app
const app = express();

// Load environment variables from .env file
dotenv.config();

// Set the port from environment variables or default to 7000
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 7000;

// Get the MongoDB connection URL from environment variables
const MONGOURL = process.env.MONGO_URL;

// Connect to MongoDB and start the server
mongoose.connect(MONGOURL).then(() => {
  console.log("Database connected successfully.");
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
  });

});

PORT = 8000
MONGO_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/dbconnect"

The setup is very basic and I have no clue on how to solve it.
I have tried using a wide variety of connection strings by using localhost, 127.0.0.1, or 0.0.0.0.

This question is similar to: Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Node.js driver. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Are you sure, you use the same connection string in your code as connecting (and working) with mongosh?

"I am trying to connect to MongoDB compass" - that's not possible. MongoDB Compass is a MongoDB client application, you cannot connect to it.

Your MONGO_URL maybe wrong.
The dbconnect should be your default database name.
You can find the reference here.

Your MONGO_URL is wrong. You should add correct path mongodb://localhost:27017/dbconnect.
example :- mongodb://localhost:27017/correct path
correct path should be add

what does correct path mean specifcally? Correct path to what? I just copy the connection string and add the name of the database at the end.
